# Remove mixed data in a variable

Tags: r

I just began to use R and I have data look like this:

```
Fruit   Consumption
Apple   High
Apple   High
Orange  High    
Orange  Low
Nut Low
Nut Low
```

I would like to remove those with mixed consumption (Orange). I first tried identifying orange with the following code before removing it out.

```
df1 <- df %>% group_by(Fruit) %>% filter(Consumption =="High" & Consumption =="Low")
```

I don't know what is wrong, but R returned zero output. I also tried changing from "AND" to "OR" but I got original data this time. Please help me!

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap `any` in the `filter` statement to remove the fruits with multiple consumption.

```
library(dplyr) 

df %>% 
  group_by(Fruit) %>%
  filter(!(any(Consumption =="High") & any(Consumption =="Low")))
  #Or
  #filter(!all(c('High', 'Low') %in% Consumption))
```

You can also detect mixed consumption by counting number of unique `Consumption` values.

```
df %>% 
  group_by(Fruit) %>%
  filter(n_distinct(Consumption) == 1)
```

Comment: OP requesting to remove fruits with multiple consumption entries, `n_distinct(Consumption) == 1`?